# How to get reference to proc self inside multi-dispatch proc?

Tags: nim-lang

Is it possible to get a reference to proc by its symbol for multi-dispatch proc?

I need to auto-generate some code based on function signature, and can't get the reference to the function.

[run](https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=2ZCz) (seems like it's not showing output in the online playground)

```
import macros

macro generate_some_code*(fn: typed): typed =
  echo fn.tree_repr

proc multiply*(a: float, b: float): float = generate_some_code(multiply)

proc multiply*(a: string, b: string): string = generate_some_code(multiply)

discard multiply(1.0, 1.0)
discard multiply("A", "x")
```

Output:

```
Sym "multiply"
ClosedSymChoice
  Sym "multiply"
  Sym "multiply"
```

It has reference to the self in the first case, but not in the other. How to get the reference to self in the second case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to work with signature of proc then restructure your code like:

```
import macros

macro generate_some_code*(fn: typed): typed =
  echo fn.tree_repr

generate_some_code:
  proc multiply*(a: float, b: float): float = discard

generate_some_code:
  proc multiply*(a: string, b: string): string = discard

# assuming that generate_some_code will modify body and return it, so it is defined
discard multiply(1.0, 1.0)
discard multiply("A", "x")
```